# How to reshape dataframe with multiple columns to expected dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of text files that need to be in one dataframe, so I read files and concatenate them to one. however, resulted dataframe has multiple columns (452 columns),but I want to reshape this dataframe to a customized one. I mean I only want to have two columns like `0` and `1` column; Here is how my data looks like:

[image]

here is what I tried on my data:

```
import pandas as pd

allfiles=glob.glob('C:\\fake\\*.txt')
dfs=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, header = None, sep = '\n', quoting=3, skip_blank_lines = True).T for file in allfiles], axis=1)
```

now I want simple reshape this resulted dataframe with onle two columns such as `0` and `1`. how can I do that? any idea?

**update: desired output**:

here is my expected output (just example):

```
d = {'headline': ["Alex Jones Vindicated  something", "California Surprisingly ", "Mexicans Are Chomping something"], 
     'context': ["Alex Jones, purveyor of somethig long text", "Setting Up Face-Off With Trump ", "Mexico has been unfairly "]}

 pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

**update2: original data**

here is how the original text file looks like (I am reading multiple text files into one dataframe with only two columns):

```
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext

longtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtext
```

Comment: You mean you only want a column for the you text files? try `df.T`?

Comment: @MohitMotwani no, that's not what I want. please see my updated post where I put reproducible output there?

Comment: Uhm, We can't reproduce your output if we don't even know what we're reshaping

Comment: @MohitMotwani I updated my post with reproducible input data and reproducible expected output. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply get rid of the outermost axis specification; i.e., instead of

```
In [44]: pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, header = None, sep = '\n', quoting=3, skip_blank_lines = True).T for file in allfiles], axis=1)
Out[44]:
        0       1       0       1       0       1
0  test1a  test1b  test2a  test2b  test3a  test3b
```

do

```
In [45]: pd.concat(pd.read_csv(file, header=None, sep='\n', quoting=3, skip_blank_lines=True).T for file in allfiles)
Out[45]:
        0       1
0  test1a  test1b
0  test2a  test2b
0  test3a  test3b
```

**Edit**, now that the post has been edited:

For example, with the following inputs:

```
In [79]: !cat blah.test
test1a

test1b
In [80]: !cat blah2.test
test2a

test2b
In [81]: !cat blah3.test
test3a

test3b
In [82]: allfiles
Out[82]: ['blah.test', 'blah2.test', 'blah3.test']
```

we get the desired output:

```
In [83]: pd.concat(pd.read_csv(file, header=None, sep='\n', quoting=3, skip_blank_lines=True).T for file in allfiles)
Out[83]:
        0       1
0  test1a  test1b
0  test2a  test2b
0  test3a  test3b
```

**Edit #2**, based on the comments below:

At least one of your files contains more than two non-empty lines and further processing is required. In your case, I would probably do something like

```
In [169]: df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(file, header=None, sep='\n', quoting=3, skip_blank_lines = True).T for file in allfiles).reset_index(drop=True).fillna('')

In [170]: df_clean = pd.DataFrame({'headline': df[0], 'context': df.loc[:, 1:].apply(' '.join, axis=1)})

In [171]: df_clean.head()
Out[171]:
                                            headline                                            context
0   Alex Jones Vindicated in "Pizzagate" Controversy  "Alex Jones, purveyor of the independent inves...
1                            THE BIG DATA CONSPIRACY  Government and Silicon Valley are looking to e...
2  California Surprisingly Lenient on Auto Emissi...  Setting Up Face-Off With Trump "California's c...
3  Mexicans Are Chomping at the Bit to Stop NAFTA...  Mexico has been unfairly gaining from NAFTA as...
4  Breaking News: Snapchat to purchase Twitter fo...  Yahoo and AOL could be extremely popular over ...
```

Comment: Probably one of your files contains more than two non-empty lines. To figure out which one, let `df` be the result of the above operation and take a look at `df[df[2].notnull()]`.

Comment: I added the example I used to the post; it matches the form of your given input exactly, so at least one of your input files must be malformed. You can use `df[df[2].notnull()]` to figure out which one(s)

Comment: And the code works completely fine using that as an example. Did you investigate the third column to see when it becomes non-null? Either do that, or supply all of your input files.

Comment: I tried to see why it happens, maybe pandas truncate long text in the second column and give a value of `NaN`. here is a list of sample data that you can explore: [link](https://jmp.sh/b/ZnRhRO6NrFH0m5rKGBHB), I don't understand why long text becomes shorten in dataframe and produced an extra column. How can I fix this? any thought?

Comment: In that example, `biz02.txt` contains 4 non-empty lines where all other files contain at most 2 non-empty lines. You will want to other preprocess the input prior to loading it into a DataFrame, or use pandas itself to do the clean-up.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.